# How to use rails runner to run a task with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, command, task, thor

Now I want to run a task under a rails project.
I want to catch a parameter when I run it.

If I use `thor` > http://whatisthor.com , I can catch parameters but it seems can't access the rails' active record.

I want to run a task like:

```
bundle exec rails runner MyTask hello --params1 '1' --params2 '2'
```

I got errors:

```
ERROR: "rails_runner help" was called with arguments ["--params1", "1", "--params2", "2"]
Usage: "rails_runner help [COMMAND]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thor` is OK. After I try again. It can use `Active Record`.

Then I can run the batch like this:

```
./bin/rails runner MyTask hello A --from B
```